# With the Uber Ride Requests API, is it possible for my application to pay on behalf of the user?

Tags: node.js, uber-api

I'm trying to build a concierge service, that picks up users and drops them off at a restaurant. Is it possible for me to pay for that ride. And if possible, never having them login to their Uber account?

Comment: If they don't need to login, then Uber doesn't know who they are.  So are you basically asking if you can request rides for other people using your own (business) account?  And presumably have more than a single ride in progress concurrently in that account?

Comment: @JohnZwinck that's a good point. I guess users would have to login at first, but do that once, then we can provide the user profile, but handle the payment our self. I don't think this exists in Uber's API though.